# gotoxy() implementation for Linux using printf

Tags: c, printf

I was looking for a substitute of gotoxy() for gcc compiler and found this -

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
```

I want to know how is it functioning, I mean when do we use `[` and `;` inside printf, what is `0x1B` doing there and how does it take the cursor to the row/column with this code?

I have never seen this type of practice for printf in books,so it would be great If you could point me to a link where I can find about such uses of printf.

Comment: It seems unusual to use `%c` to format a constant. The following would be equivalent: `printf("\x1b[%d;%df",y,x);`

Comment: Yea, popular is also `'\033'`. If I used `%c` format specifier, I'd write it as `27` - which I knew well to be ESC (a.k.a. `Ctrl-[` or `^[`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is using [terminal escape codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) to position the cursor.

`"\x1B"` is the escape character that tells your terminal that what comes next is not meant to be printed on the screen, but rather a command to the terminal (or most likely terminal emulator)

The trailing 'f' indicates that you want to force the cursor position somewhere, indicated by the coordinates that precede it.

```
Force Cursor Position   <ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}f
```

So if you call `gotoxy(4,2)`, it ends up sending the escape sequence `"(ESC)[2;4f"` where `ESC` is the byte `0x1B`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon! It was really helpful and easy to understand.

Comment: My pleasure. I recently had to do a lot of interpretation of these escape sequences so it immediately stuck out to me.

Comment: By the way - be careful with this technique.  It is highly dependent on the type of terminal within which the program runs.  Not all terminal emulators give the same meaning to sequences like this.

Comment: @user2532621 Understood. That's what curses and termcap are for. However, I was answering the opposite question: "What is this implementation doing?" Not "how do I implement this?"

Answer (score 3):

These are called [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences) and are derived from the [DEC VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) display terminal which was introduced in 1978.

Answer (score 1):

That is known as an ANSI escape code. I haven't seen those used in a while. Here's a page that explains about them:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code