# gotoxy() function using printf() 's position

Tags: c, linux, printf, coordinate-systems

Hello there
i am working a project which need the `gotoxy()` function
i have read [gotoxy() implementation for Linux using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683526/gotoxy-implementation-for-linux-using-printf/8683541#8683541)

i wonder why the

```html
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
```

need to change the x y order in printf, is that just to fit the coordinate system?
in my way, i change it to `printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,x,y)` to meet my needs

stil, during my using this `gotoxy()` in for loop like this:

```html
for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < 12; j++ ) {
            gotoxy( i , j );
            usleep(500000);
        }
    }
```

when i = 0 and i = 0, the cursor are on the first row
i wonder why cursor does't go to second row when i = 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of x and y matters because the names of the variables have no meaning to the operation of the gotoxy() function.

That function is outputing a terminal command sequence that moves to the specified coordinates.  When the terminal sees that command sequence and processes it, y is expected first.

By the way, be careful with this solution as this is highly dependent on the type of terminal within which the program is run.  In order to get wide terminal support with random movement and "drawing" on a terminal screen, `ncurses` or `curses` are your best bet.  They are challenging to learn at first though.

Answer (score 4):

OP: "why the need to change the x y order".
The cursor position command's format is

```
Force Cursor Position   <ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}f
```

The *need* arises because to match that format and have your `y` variable as the *ROW*, `y` comes first.  (You could rotate your screen 90 degrees instead).

OP: why cursor does't go to second row when i = 1?
The home position, at the **upper** left of the screen is the Origin being line **1**, column **1**

Note: You can put the escape character in the format,

```
printf("\x1B[%d;%df", y, x);
fflush(stdout);  // @jxh
```

Comment: showing how `<ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}f` relates to the function brought the whole thing home for me.

Answer (score 1):

The column and row positions do not start at 0 when using the terminal escape sequences. They start at 1.

You need to flush `stdout` to see the cursor move.

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GotoXY is a function or procedure that positions the cursor at (X,Y), X in horizontal, Y in vertical direction relative to the origin of the current window. The origin is located at (1,1), the upper-left corner of the window.

Answer (score -1):

The above C code worked after I converted to Android script (I think I'm using Korn Shell).

```
function gotoxy()
{
printf "\033[$1;$2f"
}
```

I've beenn using "\033[r;cH" all this time and it was working.