# gotoxy() implementation. Fractal squares

Tags: c, recursion

I'm studying recursive functions. I already "draw" a ruler in the MSDoS prompt.
Also, I read    [gotoxy() function implementation for linux using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683526/gotoxy-implementation-for-linux-using-printf/8683541#8683541)

Now I need to draw something like this:

[image]

I just need some help to start the function that will receive these parameters and draw it. I *think* the logic of fractal() is right.
Where do I start from ? What do I study? A name of a technic or something where I can start. I'll keep reading about *ANSI escape code*

Comment: You suspect that your computer needs graphical terminal rather than the text-based terminal.

Comment: Do you want the ANSI escape sequence to position the cursor?

Comment: see [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/)