# Windows made of text in C

Tags: c, windows, user-interface

What's the fastest and easiest way to do simple windows or boxes made out of text in C? Even a square with text inside would be good. I don't mean to do it with any external library, just using text.

EDIT: I'm using Windows. I see you mentioned the library windows.h, but I don't have to use it. I mean, the question is simple as it is. I just want a simple and fast way to put text inside a box, even with simple printfs.

For example:

```
printf("+-------------+\n");
printf("| HELLO WORLD |\n);
printf("+-------------+\n");
```

Comment: What character set are you using?

Comment: @onemasse what do you mean? I tried doing that stuff with "+-------+" for upper and lower borders but i don't know how to make sides and also it looks kinda ugly to me.

Comment: Depending on the character set you're using there could be some block graphic characters you could use. In DOS there's the extended ASCII set. In UTF-8 I guess there's probably some characters you could use.

For the sides you could use the pipe character "|".

Comment: @onemasse I would stick to minus signs and underscores for the horizontals.  I doan' trust no codepages:)

Comment: Standard C doesn't really have a convenient way to do graphics. The only smart ways to do things like this is to invoke non-standard, OS-specific libraries. But since you don't mention which OS this is for, the question therefore turns very broad. Please edit the question and add a tag for the intended target system (Windows, Linux, etc).

Comment: `What's the fastest and easiest way to do simple windows`: Ask that question on StackOverflow, perhaps? ... On a more serious note: Please take your time to read the FAQ and which kinds of questions are to be asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're wanting a box made out of stars, do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int r, c, row, col;
    
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Enter number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    printf("\n\n");

    for(r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
          for(c = 0; c < col; c++)
          {
                if(r > 0 && r < row - 1)
                {
                     if(c > 0 && c < col - 1)
                     {
                          printf(" ");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         printf("*");
                     }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
          }
          printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It works, and been taken from [here](http://staack.blogspot.in/2013/07/c-programming-empty-box.html), but modified a little.

Also, you had mentioned that you want to write text in it. So use the `gotoxy` function. I have provided the code for both linux and windows, as you have not mentioned the specific OS you're using.

For windows, taken from [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/66841-gotoxyint-x-int-y%3B/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy (int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord; // coordinates
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y; // X and Y coordinates
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

For Windows (not tested) and Linux, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683526/gotoxy-implementation-for-linux-using-printf):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
```

You pass the `x` and `y` coordinates in it, and it sets the cursor position. Then whatever you print using `printf` will get printed at that location.

***How does the second implementation for `gotoxy` work?***

This was the exact same question asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683526/gotoxy-implementation-for-linux-using-printf):

> This is using [terminal escape codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) to position the cursor.
>
> `"\x1B"` is the escape character that tells your terminal that what comes next is not meant to be printed on the screen, but rather a command to the terminal (or most likely terminal emulator)
>
> The trailing 'f' indicates that you want to force the cursor position somewhere, indicated by the coordinates that precede it.
>
> ```
> Force Cursor Position <ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}f
> ```
>
> So if you call `gotoxy(4,2)`, it ends up sending the escape sequence `"(ESC)[2;4f"` where `ESC` is the byte `0x1B`.

**NOTE:** If you do not want to use `windows.h`, and do it with only `printf`, do the second version. I believe that it will work in windows too, and does not require `windows.h`. Although, I cannot test it as I am working in Ubuntu, not Windows. If it doesn't work for windows, inform me, and I will edit my answer.

Comment: TBH, the 'star boxes' look better than messing about with pipes, underscores and other, sundry chars:)

Comment: @MartinJames, yup I agree.

Comment: Also, it's really annoying when you get someone else's source, you have different codepages and the boxes are now made up of greek, latin or cyrillic crap.  The stars are not above 127, so are fine.

Comment: @MartinJames, I am adding links to the answer, and editing them. You can see that, so please give some time.

Comment: Take your time,  Imma not gonna use up my downvotes on this answer, I'll need them all for the other bad questions later:)

Comment: @MartinJames, finished. You can see all the links which I have referred.

Comment: @AshishAhuja sorry but I actually don't understand what that function does (the 2nd one) Would you explain?

Comment: @AshishAhuja See Above